# EF Core - Property 'JObject.Next' is not virtual

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a JObject using a string variable as a backing field.

```
    public class StaticTable
    {
        public int StaticTableId { get; set; }
        private string _staticData;
        public JObject StaticData
        {
            get => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_staticData) ? "{}" : _staticData);
            set => _staticData = value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

When running migrations I receive the following exception:
`System.InvalidOperationException: Property 'JObject.Next' is not virtual. 'UseChangeTrackingProxies' requires all entity types to be public, unsealed, have virtual properties, and have a public or protected constructor. 'UseLazyLoadingProxies' requires only the navigation properties be virtual.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are confusing EF, it thinks you want to use `JObject` for an Sql Data type, obviously it's complaining for good reason.

Either use the [NotMapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute with a real backing property, or even better, use a [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations):

> Value converters allow property values to be converted when reading
> from or writing to the database. This conversion can be from one value
> to another of the same type (for example, encrypting strings) or from
> a value of one type to a value of another type (for example,
> converting enum values to and from strings in the database.)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<StaticTable>()
        .Property(e => e.StaticData)
        .HasConversion(
            v => ...,
            v => ...;
}
```